# Objective-C not loading correct DB

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have this code to open to a database in my app.  in NSLog its stating its opening the database correctly  regardless what i name the database

```
//path to db
-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.db"];
}

//open db
-(void)openDB {
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &bibleDb) == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(bibleDb);
        NSLog(@"Database Opened");
    } else {
        NSAssert(0,@"Database filed to open");
        NSLog(@"Database Opened");
    }
}
```

so regardless if I named the database `@"db1.db"` or `@"dbxxx.db"`  etc  it still says it opens fine.

Its an existing database where/how should I add the file?
Im running on xcode5

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite3_open()` *creates* the database if it does not exist.
It is equivalent to `sqlite3_open_v2()` with the 
`SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` flags.

To open only an existing database, use

```
sqlite3_open_v2([[self filePath] UTF8String], &bibleDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL)
```

Your code tries to open the database in the application "Document" directory.
If you want to package the database with your app, add it as a resource to
the Xcode target. Then in your app, you can either copy it from the application bundle to
the Document directory (if necessary), or open it directly from the application bundle
using the path

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db1" ofType:@"db"];
```

Comment: Just a reminder to the OP - if you do open the db from the application bundle, the db will be read-only.